# php How to retrieve value of a key from this weird dimensional array

Tags: php

I am learning Php these days. I have seen different kinds of arrays (multidimensional), but I have never seen one as below which got produced from ldap_search result.

**Here is the ldap_search result array:**

```
Array(
    [count] => 1[0] => Array(
        [objectclass] => Array(
            [count] => 2[0] => sudorole[1] => top
        ) [0] => objectclass[sudohost] => Array(
            [count] => 1[0] => abcd
        ) [1] => sudohost[sudocommand] => Array(
            [count] => 1[0] => ALL
        ) [2] => sudocommand[description] => Array(
            [count] => 1[0] => defg
        ) [3] => description[sudooption] => Array(
            [count] => 1[0] => !authenticate
        ) [4] => sudooption[sudouser] => Array(
            [count] => 5[0] => john[1] => james[2] => william[3] => robo[4] => chris
        ) [5] => sudouser[cn] => Array(
            [count] => 1[0] => ffffff
        ) [6] => cn[count] => 7[dn] => cn = bbbbb,ou = test,dc = myproj,        dc = com
    )
)
```

Actually my task is to findout `'dn'` value from above array.

I am able to retrieve value of a specific  key from a normal multi-dimensional array using some recursive function. But how do I retrieve value of a key from above kind of array. Using some kind of recursive function? Sorry if its dumb question, but I don't really understand, how to do it.

**BTW, I tried using the code below, but felt some logic is not correct for my array**

```
<?php
// Find the value of a Key
function seekKey($haystack, $needle){
  foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
    if($key == $needle){
      $output = $value;
    }elseif(is_array($value)){
      $output = seekKey($value, $needle);
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: @b0s3 i updated above in my post

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function that does what you want.

`searchKey` will return true if it found something. This way, you can check if it succeded before manipulating the result.

The result will be stored in the third argument of the function.

```
<?php
function searchKey($key, $array, &$result = null)
{
    if (is_array($array))
    {
        foreach ($array as $k => $arr)
        {
            if ($k == $key)
            {
                $result = $arr;
                return true;
            }
            else if (searchKey($key, $arr, $result)) // recursion
                return true;
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}

$array = [
    'count' => 1,
    0 => [
        'test' => [0, 1],
        't' => 4
    ]
];

// searchKey will return true if it found it
// $result will contain what it found
var_dump(searchKey('test', $array, $result));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I can able to do above way using nested foreach's but Iam looking for a solution using some recursive function., like my recursive example above

Comment: It is recursive (`else if (searchKey($key, $arr, $result))`)